# How to allow an activex object to print?

Tags: c#, printing, activex

I have an ActiveX control in my web page to print out bills. It works fine on local but when I try in remote server, I can't print out, it gives me this error.

System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Drawing.Printing.PrintingPermission, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, here steps are

1) Add your site to Trusted Zone

2) Then type these commands in command prompt. If you use 64-bit MSIE please use the both of these commands. I use .NET Framework 2.0, if you use other version please check and change the path of caspol.exe tool

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -machine -quiet -addgroup Trusted_Zone -site ip_address_or_site FullTrust -name give_a_name_to_your_exception -description "Give a description to your exception"

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -machine -quiet -addgroup Trusted_Zone -site ip_address_or_site FullTrust -name give_a_name_to_your_exception -description "Give a description to your exception"

Answer (score 3):

The Role of user which your app is running under, doesn't have the permission to print. Please give that user, a permission to print.

or check your application's **.Net Trust Level** (you can find it in **Features View** of your web application in IIS Management console)

Add this attribute above you method, in which you are making the ActiveX object and requesting print.

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
public void blabla
[
   //your code
}
```

Comment: "The Role of user which your app is running under, doesn't have the permission to print. Please give that user, a permission to print."

but how?

Comment: Add the code above you method where you are making the instance of Active X object and sending request to print. [see my updated answer for code]